# apollo-server-hapi authorization validate callback is not executed

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-server, hapi

Trying to run apollo-server in hapi. I have working cookie authorization in hapi, but I can't control queries to graphql. validateFunc is not called on graphql queries.

validateFunc is called after login with http://localhost:8080/login
But queries to http://localhost:8080/graphql do not call validateFunc.
If i'll set auth mode of graphql to required, i'll receive not authorizaed error, but validateFunc still not called.

```
const Hapi = require("@hapi/hapi"); //v18.3.2
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require("apollo-server-hapi"); //v2.8.1

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    _: String
  }

  type Mutation {
    _: String
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {},

  Mutation: {}
};

const runServer = async () => {
  const server = new Hapi.server({ port: 8080 });
  await server.register(require("@hapi/cookie"));
  server.auth.strategy("session", "cookie", {
    cookie: {
      name: "test-project",
      password:
        "long-long-password-long-long-password-long-long-password-long-long-password",
      isSecure: false
    },

    validateFunc: async (request, session) => {
      console.log("Why it is not called on graphql queries???");

      return { valid: true, credentials: "account" };
    }
  });

  server.auth.default("session");

  //GRAPH QL!
  const graphqlServer = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    context: async function(q) {
      console.log("Graphql context was called!");
      return q;
    },
    introspection: false,
    playground: true,
    route: {
      options: {
        auth: {
          mode: "try"
        }
      }
    }
  });

  server.route([
    {
      method: "GET",
      path: "/login",
      handler: function(request, h) {
        request.cookieAuth.set({ id: "key" });

        return "LOGIN!";
      },
      options: {
        auth: {
          mode: "try"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      method: "GET",
      path: "/test",
      handler: function(request, h) {
        console.log("TEST");
        return "OK";
      },
      options: {
        auth: {
          mode: "try"
        }
      }
    }
  ]);

  await graphqlServer.applyMiddleware({
    app: server,
    route: {
      auth: { mode: "try" }
    }
  });

  await graphqlServer.installSubscriptionHandlers(server.listener);

  await server.start().then(() => {
    console.log(`  Server ready at ${server.info.uri}/graphql `);
  });
};

runServer();
```

Expecting graphql queries execute hapi's validateFunc()